# iPhone network communication with pc

Tags: iphone, networking

I want to make an iPhone app and an application (server) which runs on a PC with Windows. Is there any easy way to do this on the client side (the iPhone), like a library or something?

Looking on Google I found [cocoaasyncsocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) and [xmppframework](http://code.google.com/p/xmppframework/wiki/iPhone), but the last commits were done some time ago and before I start my project I want to know if there are other (better) possibilities out there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to run a web server on the PC, with a set of REST-based services.  This approach gives you lots of options for implementation on the server-side, and you'll have lots of possible frameworks to choose from on the client-side as well.  One framework you could use on the iPhone is [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/).

There are lots of advantages to using a web-based approach.  There are HTTP frameworks built for almost every device and platform, so if you ever want to interact with the server from the web, an Android device, etc., there will be many tools to help you do that.  There are also lots of great tools out there for debugging HTTP interactions.

You could also use a SOAP-based API, but in my opinion SOAP tends to be more complicated than its worth.

Comment: thank you for the response. ASIHTTPRequest pretty much does it all from what I see, and is also very well documented